# Save cat command output to file

Tags: linux, bash, git, cat

I am saving the progress status of the git clone command using the below,

```
git clone --progress "https://giturl/repo.git" &> "/var/log/bitbucket.log
```

When using the cat command to see the contents of the file, such as

```
cat bitbucket.log
```

I get the below output, which is what I need,

```
Cloning into 'xyz'...
POST git-upload-pack (342 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 2682, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1237/1237), done.
remote: Total 2682 (delta 1395), reused 2514 (delta 1316)
Receiving objects: 100% (2682/2682), 21.63 MiB | 10.32 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1395/1395), done.
```

However, when I open the file bitbucket.log, using nano, any other editor or directly from WinSCP, I get the following output,

```
Cloning into 'xyz'...
POST git-upload-pack (342 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 2682, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/1237)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1237/1237), done.[K
Receiving objects:   0% (1/2682)
...
Receiving objects:  98% (2629/2682), 15.67 MiB | 10.32 MiB/s   
remote: Total 2682 (delta 1395), reused 2514 (delta 1316)[K
Resolving deltas: 100% (1395/1395)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (1395/1395), done.
```

I omitted most of the lines but you can understand how it is, it shows the progress from 0% to 100% for all actions.

Is there a way to save the cat command output to a file, exactly the same way as shown in the first output above please?

Thank you.

Comment: If you *didn't* redirect the output to file, you would notice some of those lines seemingly changing "in place". There are control characters embedded in the file which alter how the terminal displays the output of `cat`, while your editor shows them as `[K`.

Comment: Understood, but is there a way to save the cat output after it's being processed, parsed?

Comment: @croussou: Capture the terminal window buffer?

Comment: Sure, that could be an option, but can I assume that there is no other way? Because if I capture the terminal window buffer, then I need to remove certain lines from the file before it reaches its final format. Please also note that the script goes through 30 repos so it will not be ideal to change all of them one by one.

Comment: You can use something like `sed` to remove all contents between `\n` and `\r` (including `\r`).

Comment: you can open the file in vim, press `:` and run the following substitution: `%s/^.*\r//`

Comment: also, as @MartinPrikryl said, you can run this sed command: `sed -i '' $'s/^.*\r//' /var/log/bitbucket.log`

Comment: Why not simply remove the `--progress` option from the git command?

Comment: I would like to use that output basically as a log file, to check whether there were any errors in the git clone process and send those reports automatically via email at EoD.

Answer (score 2):

here are three easy options (one & two are the same as my comments above):

1. you can use regex-based text substitution in an editor like vim to edit the file, i.e. open the file, type <kbd>:</kbd> and run the substitution `%s/^.*^K//`, where `^K` is written by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. you can use `sed` to edit the file in the same way:
   `sed -i '' $'s/^.*\x0B//' /var/log/bitbucket.log`
3. you can use sed to edit the stream as it's being piped into the file in the first place:
   `git clone --progress "https://giturl/repo.git" 2>&1 | sed $'s/^.*\x0B//' >/var/log/bitbucket.log`

when I run `git clone --progress` on my system I get cr characters instead of vertical tabs, so I originally had `\r` instead of `\x0B`.

Comment: I went with option 3, as it seems to be the most ideal in my case, however, when issuing the command, I now get the below,

Cloning into 'xyz'...
remote: Counting objects: 2682, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1237/1237), done.[K
remote: Total 2682 (delta 1395), reused 2514 (delta 1316)[K
Receiving objects: 100% (2682/2682), 21.63 MiB | 11.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1395/1395), done.

Any final thoughts please?

Comment: Basically I get the [K character :)

Comment: you've written the sed command with a `$` and single quotes, right? when I write it in any other way I get a different result from sed (maybe because it's not interpreting the `\r` as a literal carriage return character)

Comment: yes, that is correct

git clone --progress https://giturl/repo.git 2>&1 | sed $'s/^.*\r//' > output.log

Comment: `[K` isn't a CR character, it's a Vertical Tab (VT) character, which can be used to "erase from the character under the cursor to end of line" ([source](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html), search for "Ctl-K").

Comment: To match it in the `sed` command you can type Ctrl-V then Ctrl-K which will write a `^K` that corresponds to the control character, or you can use the `\x0B` notation

Comment: I don't think so, AFAIK `\r` and `\n` are special notations that aren't generalized to the other control characters

Comment: So based on what you proposed earlier, with Ctrl-V and Ctrl-K, how will my line will look like in the end please? I have tried with \v though and it does not work, as in | sed $'s/^.*\r\v//' unless of course I am doing something wrong here.

BTW guys, thanks all of you for your replies and help, a few more tweaks I guess and we will get there.

Comment: I'd use `sed '/\x0B/d'` (or `sed '/^K/d'` where you write the `^K` with ctrl-v+ctrl-k), it deletes lines that contain the VT control character

Comment: the segments with the control characters don't end in a newline on my system, but I'm also getting carriage returns instead of vertical tabs so it could be a difference that only applies to me.

Comment: on my system, `sed $'/\x0B/d'` deletes all the `remote: foo object: 100% (281/281), done.` lines entirely, but `sed $'s/^.*\x0B//'` works. again, though, might be another quirk of the platform/version of something i'm using.

Comment: It seems that whatever I try I cannot get that character removed from the end of line, so from WinSCP editor it looks like [K and from terminal using nano, ^[[K, so frustrating. If it was only for my reference, honestly I would have kept it, but I want to send it to others as a status report for the repos.

Comment: in that case i think it might be a different control character altogether, not a vt—try this `sed` command instead and see if it works: `git clone --progress "https://giturl/repo.git" 2>&1 | sed $'s/^.*\x1B\[K//' >/var/log/bitbucket.log`